# Add Ansible Template as RPC dependancy for Privilege Vault/Secret Server

Tags: ansible, pam

We're running Delinea/Thycotic Privilege Vault in our environment.

We're trying to onboard all credentials into Privilege Vault as much as possible, so that we can leverage Auto-Change, where the password is rotated by Privilege Vault every X days.

Whereas using the Remote File and Application Pool Recycle dependencies works in many instances, there are other instances where we would like to trigger an Ansible Playbook after an RPC in Privilege Vault. Has anyone been able to add an Ansible Playbook as a dependency for an RPC?

Comment: Yes, there is the possibility for Delinea Secret Server [Advanced Scripting](https://delinea.com/products/secret-server/features/advanced-scripting) and [If/Then automation](https://delinea.com/products/secret-server/features/automatic-password-management#section6).

Comment: Hi, @U880D can you expand on your answer a bit? How would I initiate the Ansible AWX playbook?

Comment: Because of the lack of testing environment and documentation access for the commercial application in question (Delina Secret Server, formerly known as Thycotic) I haven't provided an answer but a comment. The software vendor (Delina) itself states it is possible to trigger 3rd party scripts, applications, etc. I know from my own infrastructure that the service in question (Delina) has such capabilities and can do so. Because of the first sentence I can't provide more information.